# Destroy session in cakephp when you leave the page?

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

How and where can I use

```
$this->Session->destroy()
```

For the session to be destroyed whenever the page is closed?

And how can I keep the session open until the page is closed, independent of time?

I need this because when the User enters the page, some specific variables are unset in the session, and when he comes out, I need this session to be destroyed.
  I'm not able to do this using cakephp.

Answer (score 1):

Sessions are stored on the server, so if the browser is closed or the user goes to a different page, there is no obligation that it informs the server about this action.

Session are stored for a certain time in the server, and after some time of inactivity or if you properly logout, it will be destroyed there automatically.

Check Sessions info in [CakePHP cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html) for more info regardin Sessions

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `$(window).unload(function(){alert('Closing browser')});`

And do ajax call to server to destroy session , but this may not work on some browsers and already deprecated function in jQuery 1.8 for more info 
http://api.jquery.com/unload/

Answer (score 0):

if you have used Auth cakephp 3.0 components then no need to do anything all session and cookie management carried by session core components.

$this->Session->destroy()

it will destroy all cookie and session data but if you want to destroy particular session then you can do by this code

$this->Session->destroy('$val');

here,$val represents particular session to destroy